# Can't build successfully project in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I can't build successfully project in VS2010 it shows me error:

> **`"Error    579 Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\DT.Eagle.Zones.dll" to "bin\Debug\DT.Eagle.Zones.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\DT.Eagle.Zones.dll' because it is being used by another process."`**

When I close Visual Studio and open it again and try to build the project, it build successfully, but after I edit the code and try to build the project it shows me the same error. Then I have to close VS after every time I edit the code to build the project successfully.

Any idea how to fix this thing?

Comment: Something is causing the DLL to be loaded by visual studio itself - it doesn't normally do this. What type of project(s) are in the solution?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There are a lot of solutions in my project. But earlier it didn't show the error.It appeared when I added new windows form to DT.Eagle.Zones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like when you restart Visual Studio and rebuild the project, some process starts which is accessing `bin\Debug\DT.Eagle.Zones.dll` that's why system cannot overwrite existing file as its locked by another process.

Comment: check in task manager which processes are running and if any of them looks familiar to your program. Also debug your code as somewhere in your code you are using that `dll`. Maybe your program is not shutting down properly and keeps on running in background which keep a lock on `dll`.